# Amount deposited not being recorded in contract

Tags: smart-contract, cleos

I'm learning to make my own contract and I'm having a hard time getting LNX that is transferred to the contract to be recorded ad a balance.

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio/asset.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract]] elevated : public eosio::contract {

  public:
    const symbol _symbol;
    elevated(name receiver, name code, datastream<const char*> ds ):contract(receiver, code, ds),_symbol("LNX", 8) {}

    [[eosio::action]]
    void login (name username) {
      require_auth(username);
      users_table _users(get_self(), get_first_receiver().value);
      auto iterator = _users.find(username.value);

      if (iterator == _users.end()) {
        iterator = _users.emplace(username, [&](auto& new_user) {
          new_user.username = username;
        });
      }

    };

    [[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]]
    void deposit(name from, name to, eosio::asset quantity, std::string memo) {
      if (from == get_self() || to != get_self())
      {
        print("This doesnt print");
        return;
      }
      balance_table _balance(get_self(), from.value);
      auto iterator = _balance.find(_symbol.raw());

      if (iterator == _balance.end())
        iterator = _balance.emplace(get_self(), [&](auto& new_balance) {
          new_balance.funds = quantity;
        });
      else _balance.modify(iterator, get_self(), [&](auto& new_balance) {
        new_balance.funds += quantity;
      });
    }

  private:

    struct [[eosio::table]] user_info {
      name username;
      auto primary_key() const {
        return username.value;
      }
    };
    typedef eosio::multi_index<name("users"), user_info> users_table;

    struct [[eosio::table]] balance {
      eosio::asset funds;
      uint64_t primary_key() const { 
        return funds.symbol.raw();
        }
    };
    typedef eosio::multi_index<name("balance"), balance> balance_table;

};
```

I'm calling the contract with `cleos -u https://testnet.lynx.eosdetroit.io:443 transfer account00001 account00002 '1.00000000 LNX' 'Test Balance' -p account00001@active`

Comment: This is a poor question. https://testnet.lynx.eosdetroit.io:443 does not exist - which network are you trying to access? EOS testnet? Wax testnet? The account names are both illegal names. The cleos command is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

Problem 1:
The `cleos transfer` function is only for transferring EOS, if you want to transfer a different token you have to do it like this:
`cleos push action CONTRACT_NAME transfer '{"from":"account00001","to":"account00002","quantity":"1.00000000 LNX","memo":"Test Balance" -p account00001`

The second problem is account names in EOS can not have a `0` in them, so the accounts you want to send money from and to can't succeed with the account names you specified.
Allowed names are lower case, 12 characters or less, and may contain numbers 1-5 and a period (`.`)

Comment: @Bill was this helpful? If so you should accept the answer and upvote in order to help others in the future